# Alternative to GeoNode? Running Python3, Django2, Apache2 and GeoServer2.14

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geonode

I've developed a `QGIS` plugin ([The QGIS repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geodatafarm/), [GeoDataFarm homepage, with a tutorial](https://www.geodatafarm.com)), that I now want to transfer to the web. The reason for transfer it to the web is mainly to able to limit the amount of information/buttons for the user and I believe that there is a too high threshold for the users (farmers) of the plugin to use `QGIS`.

Anyhow, I have a server that stores data in a PostgreSQL database (with PostGIS), and I have managed to set up a `GeoServer` that can connect to the database and supply a WMS service, but it was a lot of work in the "GeoServer environment" ([and in QGIS to create the styling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R58EggReZtU)), that I want to transfer via Python to my webpage. So I looked around for options and understood that much of the work could be done by GeoNode. But I run the webpage with `Python3`, `Django 2.1.2`, `Apache2`, and I understood that GeoNode is still running `Python 2.7`, etc. So are there any alternatives for GeoNode working with `Python3/GeoServer/PostgreSQL` etc?

Answer (score 2):

One option to transfer layers and styles between QGIS and Geoserver is the 
[GeoServer Explorer Plugin](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-geoserver-plugin) for QGIS. It will make your workflow more friendly.

Install it from source. It will run on QGIS 3, if you install from source. QGIS 3 support for SLD is better in QGIS 3, but still has some limitations.

You can use Geonode to publish data (and it will be stored in Postgresql and published by Geoserver). But if you already have Geoserver up and running, I don't see any advantage in installing Geonode, just to publish WMS maps.